# proccess bar base on time limitation in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to make function that brings the ability of getting to stored times and calculating stock values.

## Logic

1. process bar will get products `start` and `end` discount time `this
   will be duration of (amount) of process bar`
2. on process bar I need to count total stock of product minus what has
   been sold and return the numbers

## sample

[image: screen 1]

If you like to see live sample [this website](https://shopee.co.id/) is using it.

## Code

currently I do not have any code to show here for this matter, what I need is `help to start` or `suggestions` of what plugins etc that i can use to achieve this, or maybe you have any sample code that I can work with it.

Thanks.

## UPDATE

I have 2 values in my blade that I would like to show the result of that in progress bar and show custom note as the result reaches to certain amounts.

## Logic

I have `$discount->stock` [***comes from discount table***] and `$disount->products->stock` [***comes from products table***] at the first value of them are the same, for example `40` `40`. By the time `$disount->products->stock` will be less on sells till become `0` but `$discount->stock` will stay `40`.

> Now what I try to do is to `minus(-)` this two values `40 - 40` and
>   return result in progress bar but the result are inverse.

**Meaning** when at the first both columns are `40` my progress bar is empty (not filled) but text above progress bar will say (as sample) `40 left` and when become to `40` , `10` says `30` left and so on... .

Answer (score 0):

Use a progress bar to do this. Bootstrap has many examples [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/progress/).

You might do this following:

```
// your html
<div class="progress">
    <div id="progess-bar" class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>

// using jquery to get product information. product id 1 for example
$.ajax({
    url: '/products/1',
    done: data => {
        $('#progess-bar').attr('aria-valuenow', data.currentStock / data.totalStock)
        $('#progess-bar').text(data.currentStock + ' out of ' + data.totalStock')
    }
})
```

Comment: i this this part `style="style="width: 25%" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"` must change to get effect from ajax code also need get id of each product otherwise will set same data for all products am i right?

Comment: Yes exactly, my example would simply need to update the url for a single product, then you can reuse it for all the products you need.

Comment: no doubt on that. i mean from html code which part i should replace with which part of jquery code to get it done?

Comment: You would set the `valuenow` attribute to update it as a percentage of available vs total. `$('#progess-bar').attr('aria-valuenow', data.currentStock / data.totalStock)`. min should stay 0 and max should be 1. That will give you a ratio like .60 left in stock.

Comment: i'll try it and get back to you if i got problem with it. thanks